# Teleporting PacMan to other side of the Maze

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, pacman, collider

I'm creating a teleporting for my PacMan game to get to the other side of the maze when triggered. I have the code then but when colliding nothing happens. I need that when i trigger the Left Portal i go to the right portal. I am thinking that the Pathfinding i have might be the problem. Thanks

**Portal Code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Portal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform warpTarget;

    void onTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        Debug.Log("An Object Collided");
        other.gameObject.transform.position = warpTarget.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check for the methods's name. It must start with an **uppercase** **char instead of an lowercase**, so it should be something like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
     Debug.Log("An Object Collided");
     other.gameObject.transform.position = warpTarget.position;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that all Unity functions are UpperCamelCase

Comment: @Prodigle `s/Unity/C#`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines